# Is there a any method to find the seed node list in a Cassandra Cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, cqlsh, nodetool, nosql

Is it possible to find the seed node ip in a cluster using nodetool or cqlsh other than having to look into the *cassandra.yaml* configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, at least not as of version 3.0.